# Change the PS1 prompt in a subshell sh called from parent bash

Tags: bash, shell, bashrc, profile, subshell

When I am running an interactive `bash` session, I sometimes experiment with `sh`.

I call `sh` directly from this `bash` session.

My question is, how can I change the `PS1` prompt of this subshell?

I would like the prompt to be something like `sh$`, notifying me that I am using `sh` and not `bash`.

What I have tried so far is:

- I made a configuration file analogous to `.bashrc` named `.shrc`
- I put only one line in it: `export PS1='$(echo ${0})\$ '`
- I then modified `~/.profile` to say the following:

  ```bash
  # if running bash
  if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  # include .bashrc if it exists
      if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
          . "$HOME/.bashrc"
      fi
  # if running another shell
  else
      if [ -f "$HOME/.shrc" ]; then
          . "$HOME/.shrc"
      fi
  fi
  ```
- I restarted the terminal, but the changes are not being applied.
- If I run `. ~/.shrc` in `sh` manually, the changes *do* get applied.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't source that file by default. You can direct it to do so:

```
ENV=~/.shrc sh
```

Or you might add:

```
alias sh="PS1='\$0\$ ' sh"
```

To your usual shell's environment file. It could simplify things.

Or even:

```
alias sh='ENV=~/.shrc sh'
```

Still, if you only want to declare the one variable for it, explicitly setting `$PS1` on the command line like in the first `alias` example is probably the better way to go.

Comment: Nice solutions! What is going on with all the single apostrophes in `alias sh='PS1='\''$0\$ '\'' sh'`?

Comment: @Netfas - You can't put a hard quote within a hard-quoted string, but you can quote a hard quote though like `"'"` or `\'`. So what those do is close the current string like `'current string'` wedges a backslash quoted hard quote in like `\'` then starts a new one like `'next string'` - and they all get concatenated. `'string'\''string'`

Comment: And we need the hard quotes to prevent premature expansion of the `$0\$` part (`alias sh="PS1='$0\$ ' sh"` results in `bash$`), right?

Comment: @Netfas - right `$PS1` is special - it is `eval`ed at each prompt. So you need the shell script in there, not the expansion of the variables. Especially since when you call it on the command line, it isn't even `$0` yet - that's still `bash` at that time. If you do `alias sh="PS1'$0\$ ' sh"` - you're quoting the hardquotes - and `$0` is expanded. But this would work: `alias sh="PS1='\$0\$ ' sh"`.

Comment: @Netfas - actually, on second thought that's wrong - it's not about when you call it on the command line, it's about protecting `$0` at `alias` definition time. Sorry about that. Anyway, the command still works, I just got ahead of myself I guess. And by the way, [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124904/52934) makes for a pretty handy prompt in `sh` mode.

Comment: Awesome! I am definitely going to try that :)

Comment: One thing is still bothering me: what configuration file for `sh` is being read when you you call a subshell in `bash`? I mean, the subshell has a default `PS1` of `$`, where does that come from? Where is that default defined?

Comment: @Netfas - In the executable - it's compiled in behavior... or maybe it's set in the link. `sh` is just a link to `bash` run like `bash --posix --norc --noprofile`. At least I think that makes all of it. You're not actually running a program all its own.